# uibutton events

Tags: uibutton

`// starting my code`

```
int col=10;

UIButton*mbybutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[mbybutton setTitle:@"Click Here"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//-------------------    
[self performSelector:@selector(fullscreen:) 
  withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:col]
       afterDelay:0.2];
//----------------------------

-(void) displayvalue:(id)iid{

    int c=[iid intValue];


    printf("\n\n ======= %d========",c);
}
// end of code
```

in this code my problem is 
these code replace 
afterDelay:0.2 by forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside  (on the mybutton's even)
 and get the value of col in displayvalue method when it touchupinside 
pls rectify these error..

Comment: This is almost completely incomprehensible. Make sure you're wrapping all your code in <code> blocks, and try to restate your question in the form of a question.

Comment: I'm guessing the question is 'What code should I put in place of the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: so that tapping the button causes displayvalue: to be called with the value of the col variable?'

Answer (score 0):

you want to go to your header file, and first declare an IBAction. Then in IB, tie up the button to that IBAction.

Then, in your .m file, you do this

```
- (IBAction)yourActionName:(id)sender {

     [okbutton disabled:TRUE];

}
```